# A large number unused wakelocks and performance

Tags: performance

There is an application that every day creates about 100-200 new wakelocks for android. each wakelock is used once and after using it is no longer needed, but remains in the system. Thus there are a lot of unused wakelocks in the system. How do you think this is correct? or is it bad for system performance?

if you are wondering what kind of application it is and how this is possible, then see the link: https://github.com/iNPUTmice/Conversations/issues/4012

Comment: The [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) suggest that keeping wakelocks longer than required is bad for battery life. So, if you want to prove to the developers that their wakelock leak has an impact, it's probably easiest to look at power consumption first. Like most performance question, there's no more general answer than "measure it".

Comment: How do you see a list of wakelocks?

Comment: for see a list of wakelocks, i use settings inside my android, I have a modified android: Havok OS https://havoc-os.com/